# Mysql RegExp Query for AND type without repeatedly using AND

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, sql-like

I have table where the fruits column has four entries:-

```
a) apple
b) banana,apple
c) orange,pear,apple
d) chiku,banana,pear,apple
```

Now I want to make query such that all rows containing apple and banana is selected.

So I tries this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE `FRUIT`  REGEXP 'apple|banana'
```

But this gives all rows having either apple or banana or both. But I want only **BOTH** case.

So what is the symbol of AND (as symbol of OR here is | )

Thanks

Comment: You do not need a REGEXP here, just `WHERE fruit LIKE '%apple%' AND fruit LIKE '%banana%'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK.....but here also instead of writing AND multiple times what can be used

Comment: `REGEXP 'apple.*banana'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In this :- WHERE fruit LIKE '%apple%' AND fruit LIKE '%banana%' How can I skip repeated AND

Comment: SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE `FRUIT`  REGEXP '(apple|banana){2}'

Comment: @parthi -- that works only if the two words are adjacent.

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('apple', fruit) AND FIND_IN_SET('banana', fruit)`